# For how many of value(s) of n, $ n \in \mathbb{N}$, $2^8 + 2^{11} + 2^{2n}$ is a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two problems on number theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57177/two-problems-on-number-theory)

> For how many of value(s) of n, $ n \in \mathbb{N}$,  $2^8 + 2^{11} + 2^{2n}$ is a perfect square?

How to do it?

Comment: One approach is just to try.  Can you see why you don't have to test $n > 11$?

Answer (score 4):

We break the problem up into two parts.  First we deal with the "open-ended" part,  where $n\ge 6$.  In this case, our expression is equal to 
$$2^8(1+2^3+2^{2n-8}).$$
Since $2^8$ is a perfect square, we need $2^{2n-8} +9$ to be a perfect square. We have the solution $2n-8=4$.  There are no other solutions with $n\ge 6$. For if $x^2$ is a perfect square, the next perfect square is $x^2+2x+1$.  So if $2^n$ is bigger than $4$, then the next perfect square after $2^{2n}$ is  $(2^{2n}+1)^2$, which is bigger than $2^{2n}+9$. We conclude that there is exactly one solution with $n \ge 6$.

Next we look at the cases $n=1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, and $5$ (and perhaps $0$ if we allow that). There is no sense in thinking too much about the matter:  we can just use the calculator.

**Comment:** The simple observation that if $x$ is an integer, then there is no perfect square strictly between $x^2$ and $(x+1)^2$ is surprisingly useful in Diophantine problems.